# xdotool command chaining

Tags: xdotool

I'd like to pause the vlc player by sending the space key to its main window.

What I tried is :

```
xdotool search --class vlc key space
```

And

```
xdotool search --classname vlc key space
```

That didn't work. What worked is :

```
xdotool search --class vlc | while read window; do xdotool key --window $window "space"; done;
```

Obviously that solution isn't taking advantage of xdotool command chaining. Would love to get feedback on that.

Some more info

```
ychaouche#ychaouche-PC 15:08:03 /usr/share/man $ xdotool search  --class "Vlc"   | nl
     1  65011874
     2  65011964
     3  65011994
     4  65011729
     5  65011747
     6  65011738
ychaouche#ychaouche-PC 15:08:45 /usr/share/man $ xdotool search  --classname "Vlc"   | nl
     1  65011874
     2  65011964
     3  65011994
     4  65011729
     5  65011747
     6  65011738
ychaouche#ychaouche-PC 15:08:49 /usr/share/man $
```

Comment: @Quasímodo it seems man page says otherwise. `Example: Send ctrl+c to all windows matching title 'gdb' (See "COMMAND CHAINING") xdotool search --name gdb key ctrl+c`

Comment: Thanks @Quasímodo, I tried --onlyvisible but the list of the windows is still the same, 3 ID listed w/ and w/o --onlyvisible.

Comment: @Quasímodo another problem I have is that sending space seems to work but sending ctrl+i (even with while loop) doesn't seem to work. Ctrl+i should open the track info page in vlc.

Comment: @Quasímodo I'm seeing two windows, the vlc player window and the playlist window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135660/discussion-between-ychaouche-and-quasimodo).